# cmake/make - unrecognized command line option "-std=c++14" - but G++ does

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, makefile, g++, c++14

I compiled `gcc` and `cmake` (in that order) in my home folder on a server today (the compiler on the server is 5 years old and I need `C++14` features...).

There is no problem when I compile something by command,

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.cc
```

But if I use `cmake .` then `make`, I got this error :

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++14"
```

**in CMakeLists.txt :**

```
add_definitions(-std=c++14)
```

**in CMakeFiles/a.out.dir/flags.make**

```
CXX_FLAGS = -I/home/jager/manufacture/usr/local/include -std=c++14
```

for information :

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.2.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.3.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

I have no idea what the fheck...

Comment: it seems that cmake is using the system's gcc; you ought to put your PATH somehow on CMakeLists.txt; see http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Comment: dude, you right! add this in an answer, I'll complete it with what I did and how people can see what compiler cmake is using...

Comment: @Massa it's still time to claim your point!

Comment: my comment was only tentative and I made it from my cell phone. It's my opinion that you expanded it and made your own (more complete and correct) answer, so, please, run with the points! :D

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're using the system compiler instead of the one you just built. Your best bet is to configure your project using your newly-compiled g++:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/your/g++ .
```

You can verify that the correct compiler is being used by performing a verbose build and looking at the `g++` path that CMake is using:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

Comment: *« your best bet is to configure your project using your newly-compiled g++ »* for me the best is to configure one for all, trough setting some environment variables. But your answer is good, you deserve at least a point.

Comment: This is actually better: when you distribute your code your users won't need to have their compilers in the same path as you. Also, this value will get stored in your `CMakeCache.txt`, so you only need to set it once. Your environment variables will get wiped out as soon as you close your terminal window.

Comment: if you set your variable as I did, you won't have to redefine them... and I don't see why other people should have the compiler in the same place. As you said, if you define the variable trough command line, then, after a logout, the compiler used will be the one installed on the system... or there is something I don't understand.

Answer (score 5):

*Massa commented:*

> it seems that cmake is using the system's gcc; you ought to put your
>   PATH somehow on CMakeLists.txt;

wich is actually right, this problem can be solved by adding in **.bashrc**:

```
CC=/home/BestPathEver/usr/local/bin/gcc
export CC

CXX=/home/BestPathEver/usr/local/bin/g++
export CXX
```

then, update your current session,

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

at this point cmake will use the good compiler *without* you to have to modify any file in your project.

let me suggest as well to add in some **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
message(STATUS "CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME          = ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}"         )
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID      = ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}"     )
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION = ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX   = ${CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX}"  )
```

those commands will returns some nice information when you'll execute,

```
$ cmake .
```

Comment: I see you've submitted your own answer. If this answers your question, please accept it so that it appears at the top of the list.

Comment: @Alex actualy I was excpecting Massa to answer... since it was his comment who helped me to solve that problem. I will accept my answer in few hours if he doesn't